# How are we to understand the word "quickly" in Revelation 22:12 according to our idea of time?

Tags: word-study, revelation

Revelation 22:12 ASV Behold, I come quickly; and my reward is with me, to render to each man according as his work is.

What is the time gap that can be derived from the use of the word quickly in this verse?

If as Jesus said "“Everyone knows what I teach. I have preached regularly in the synagogues and the Temple, where the people gather. I have not spoken in secret. John 18:20, then the understanding of this verse should be plain.

What then of the generation mentioned in Matthew 24:30-37, if the idea of time is not involved here? Is this the "time" that nobody knows except Jesus' God,? or does Jesus now know that time now that he is in heaven.?

Matthew 24:30-37 30“Then will appear the sign of the Son of Man in heaven. And then all the peoples of the earth c will mourn when they see the Son of Man coming on the clouds of heaven, with power and great glory. d 31And he will send his angels with a loud trumpet call, and they will gather his elect from the four winds, from one end of the heavens to the other.

32“Now learn this lesson from the fig tree: As soon as its twigs get tender and its leaves come out, you know that summer is near. 33Even so, when you see all these things, you know that it e is near, right at the door. 34Truly I tell you, this generation will certainly not pass away until all these things have happened. 35Heaven and earth will pass away, but my words will never pass away.

The Day and Hour Unknown

36“But about that day or hour no one knows, not even the angels in heaven, nor the Son, f but only the Father. 37As it was in the days of Noah, so it will be at the coming of the Son of Man.

Comment: It implies no time gap. Only that when it does happen, it will happen quickly.

Comment: @OrangeDog.  Soon/Quickly. implies no time Gap? Verily I say unto you, This generation shall not pass away, till all these things be accomplished. How do you understand generation in harmony with calculation of time?

Comment: "Soon" and "Quickly" are different words. They do not mean the same thing.

Comment: @OrangeDog. Some versions use soon some use quickly. You can answer the question whenever you want to.

Comment: Is the word "τάχος" (quickly) or "ἐγγύς" (soon)? There you will find your answer, and which translations are wrong.

Comment: @OrangeDog. It seems nobody know when Jesus will come again. How is this so if according to Jesus in "“Everyone knows what I teach. I have preached regularly in the synagogues and the Temple, where the people gather. I have not spoken in secret. John 18:20,. Is this the" time" that nobody knows,? If he knows, how is it that the generation that he spoke about had passed without seeing him return? Why has Paul's expectation of Jesus' return not occurred? Maybe you know?

Comment: If you want to ask about "this generation shall not pass away" then ask about that, not an unrelated passage.

Comment: As for this question, it [seems to be already answered](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/60026/meaning-of-quick-or-quickly?rq=1), or [more specifically here](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/19844/rev-311-i-come-quickly-vs-i-come-soon)

Comment: @OrangeDog. I see that you take this passage and Matthew 24:36 "generation"  as "unrelated" to Jesus return.

Comment: search thoroughly before posting.

Answer (score 2):

The adverb ταχύ (tachu) occurs 12 times in the NT, six times in the book of Revelation, five of which refer to Jesus coming "quickly".

- Rev 2:16 - Therefore repent! Otherwise I will come to you **quickly** and wage war against them with the sword of My mouth.
- Rev 3:11 - I am coming **soon/quickly**. Hold fast to what you have, so that no one will take your crown.
- Rev 22:7 - “Behold, I am coming **soon/quickly**. Blessed is the one who keeps the words of prophecy in this book.”
- Rev 22:12 - “Behold, I am coming **soon/quickly**, and My reward is with Me, to give to each one according to what he has done.
- Rev 22:20 - He who testifies to these things says, “Yes, I am coming **soon/quickly**.” Amen. Come, Lord Jesus!

Further, the cognate noun, τάχος (tachos = quickness) also occurs twice in Revelation as follows:

- Rev 1:1 - The revelation of Jesus Christ, which God gave Him to show to His bond-servants what things it behooves to take place in **quickness**. And He signified it through having sent His angel to His servant, John
- Rev 22:6 - And he said to me, "These words are faithful and true. And the Lord, the God of the spirits of the prophets, sent His angel to show His servants the things that must come to pass in **quickness**."

Thus, in Rev 22:6, 7, 12, 20, four times, we have emphasized that Jesus will come quickly or "soon", and that "***These words are faithful and true***", as if there were any doubt left!!

How can 2000 years (and dozens of generations) be interpreted as "soon/quickly"?  (Note the similar comments by Jesus in Matt 24:34 about everything being fulfilled in that generation.) Since this has been one of the greatest sources of ridicule and mockery by non-Christians, it deserves a decent answer.  Few have been proposed.  Here is a sample:

- 2000 years is still short compared to eternity past and future
- the time of Christ's coming will be "quick" because it will be unexpected and sooner than expected when it arrives as no specific time is mentioned
- the "quickness" refers to the speed of events that occur just before Jesus returns

Note the comments of Gill (on Rev 22:7) -

> **Behold, I come quickly**,.... These are the words not of the angel, but of Christ, as is manifest from Revelation 22:12 and which are to
> be understood not of Christ's coming in his power to destroy
> Jerusalem, for this was past when John had these visions, and wrote
> this book; but of the second and personal coming of Christ to
> judgment, as is clear from Revelation 22:12 which though it will not
> be sooner than the time appointed, yet will be as soon as that time is
> come, and sooner than is generally expected by men. The Ethiopic
> version adds, "as a thief", as in Revelation 16:15 and because the
> second coming of Christ is an affair of the utmost moment, and will be
> attended with events of the greatest consequence and importance, in
> which the visions of this book issue, a "behold" is prefixed to it, as
> a note of attention and admiration:

Comment: Similarly, just as the powers that be ignored Hitler's "Mein Kampf", which outlined his plans for Europe, they also ignored [Achtung – Panzer!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Achtung_%E2%80%93_Panzer!), a book that described the blitzkrieg tactics that Hitler would use to start the war. That book described how a lightning fast attack would take the enemy unawares and quickly destroy its armed forces. ¶ Both the Nazi rise to power and the opening of the war happened very *quickly*, but they didn't happen *soon*.

Comment: Is there a different word that Greek typically uses for "soon" or "fast"? I can't think of another language that uses the same word for both meanings

Comment: @Nacht - do you mean ἐγγύς (near, soon) as opposed to τάχος (quickly).  However, BDAG quotes cases where these meanings overlap.

Comment: . @Dottard. It seems nobody knows when Jesus will come again. How is this so if according to Jesus in "“Everyone knows what I teach. I have preached regularly in the synagogues and the Temple, where the people gather. I have not spoken in secret. John 18:20,. Is this the" time"  that nobody knows,?  If he knows,  how is it that the generation that he spoke about had passed without seeing him return? Why has Paul's expectation of Jesus' return not occurred?

Comment: @AlexBalilo - I am not sure what you are driving at.

Comment: @Dottard. Not sure.....? Check the 3 bulleted proposed answers in the body of your answer.

Comment: @AlexBalilo - if you wish to communicate, speak plainly and not in riddles.

Comment: There's no contradiction. "Everyone knows" what Jesus teaches, and part of his teaching was that no one would know the time of his return. You are trying to turn "Everyone knows what I teach" into "Everyone knows when I will return". They are not the same.

Comment: @PeterKirkpatrick.You can answer the Q if you want. I am not trying to turn "Everyone knows what I teach" into "Everyone knows when I will return".. That is your opinion. I am examining this verse regarding Jesus return. Those answering are free to consider everything that Jesus said and what he taught.

Answer (score 2):

**Matthew 24:6-7**

> "And you will hear of wars and rumours of wars. See that you are not alarmed, for this must take place, but the end is **not yet**."and there will be famines and  earthquakes". ESV My emphasis.

"not yet"- a long wait. Time for nation to rise against nation.

**Revelation 11:18**

> "The nations raged, [over a long time] but your wrath came, and the time for the dead to be judged, and for rewarding your servants, the prophets and saints, and those who fear your name , both small and great, and for destroying the destroyers of the earth". My bracket.

If a besieged city waits and waits for deliverance, and at last help comes, it arrives quickly but suppose the wait was caused by the length of the journey. The journey could be all  that had to happen in God's plan regarding wars, famines and earthquakes before it could arrive. Then when it does arrive it is going at great speed.

At great speed it changes everything. Quickly "the destroyers are  destroyed", quickly the servants rewarded. In a flash it all happens-

**1 Corinthians 15:52**

> "in the twinkling of an eye".

Answer (score 2):

From other scriptures we can understand that NT writers believed that Jesus would return within their own lifetime. So "quickly" probably means one generation or less.

- Truly, I say to you, this generation will not pass away till all these things take place. (Matthew 24:340; see also Luke 21:32, Mark 13:30)

The Apostle Paul also seems to have believed that he would be among those who would be alive ["we who remain"] when Jesus returned:

- the dead in Christ will rise first; then we who are alive, who remain, will be caught up together with them to meet the Lord in the air. (Thess. 4:17)

Some have suggested that "quickly" does not refer to the *when* of Jesus' coming, but the *how*. This argument fails because of the above-mentioned scriptures and especially *Revelation's* on famous prediction: "Behold I am coming soon." (22:20)

**Thus we have to conclude that "quickly" means within one generation.** It's possible, of course to interpret this--as well as the "one-generation" hope of the Gospels and Paul's expectation in 1 Thessalonians--differently. God's time is different from ours and Paul may have written of "us who remain" in a generic sense, not implying his own generation. But in any case the message is that we should "live eschatologically," believing that Jesus could appear at any moment and making ourselves ready by living according to his teaching.

Comment: ..It obviously didn't happen within that generation

Comment: @AlexBalilo TBH, it's probably a bad idea to use 'obviously' about anything related to Revelation. ;)

Comment: @AlexBalilo I don't object to 'obviously.' The expectation expressed in Revelation, along with the gospels and Paul simply was not fulfilled. But we can still live in hope.

Answer (score 2):

In the book of the Revelation, that word for 'quickly' (tachu) occurs seven times in the A.V.  Six times it is with respect to Jesus coming.

Rev.2:5 - I will come unto thee quickly, and will remove...

Rev.2:16- I will come unto thee quickly, and will fight...

Rev.3:11- I come quickly; hold that fast which...

Rev.11:14 ...behold the third woe cometh quickly.

Rev.22:7- I come quickly; blessed is he that keepeth...

Rev.22:12- I come quickly, and my reward is...

Rev.22:20- Surely I come quickly.

Now, is this speaking of shortness of time, or is it with respect to the speed of coming? An event could be thousands of years "in the pipeline", so to speak, but suddenly, it happens with a sort of explosion of speed that takes everyone by surprise.

Did not Jesus say that of himself, regarding the event of his coming? He said:

> "For as the lightning cometh out of the east and shineth even unto the
> west; so shall also the coming of the Son of man be." Matthew 24:27 &
> Luke 17:24

The quickness of the event is so sudden and so fast, that the whole world will be taken by surprise.

So, ***it's not our idea of time that is involved here***, as regards to how long it takes from the stated promise to the actual event, but ***it's the suddenness of the explosive action, when it happens***. Lightning is an excellent illustration and cannot be bettered. The quickness of lightning is breathtaking.

A "time gap" is not what this is about at all. Indeed, many of Jesus' parables warn that people will be lulled into a false sense of security because they think there's far too long a time gap from Christ's departure ("to a far country") and his return as King. Using the similarity of how house-holders never stay up to wait in case a burglar might creep in, Jesus warns:

> "Be ye therefore ready also: for the Son of Man cometh at an hour when
> ye think not... The lord of that servant will come in a day when he
> looketh not for him, and at an houor when he is not aware, and will
> cut him in sunder..." (Luke 12:40 & 48)

That's what Revelation shows, for Christians who have faith in Christ's glorious return. In every age, every generation since his ascension, the promise holds good that **he will suddenly - quickly - appear**. Nobody knows the day or the hour, but we have been told that he could return in our life-time, and so we must live our lives as if he was going to suddenly burst onto the world scene, from heaven, to usher in the Day of Resurrection and Judgment. It will happen like lightning, and **there's nothing more quick than lightning, that we can see with our eyes!**

Comment: If as Jesus said "“Everyone knows what I teach. I have preached regularly in the synagogues and the Temple, where the people gather. I have not spoken in secret. John 18:20, then the understanding of this verse should be plain. What then of the generation mentioned in Matthew 24:34, if the idea of time is not involved here? Is this the  "time" that nobody knows except Jesus' God,? or does Jesus now know that time now that he is in heaven.?

Comment: @Alex Balilo  After having answered this Q, you have added to it, changing it to such a degree, that now you are asking lots of other Qs. They may be related to your original Q, but I am not going to answer any of them, because even what I wrote prior to those new Qs being put is actually covered.  You may take your understanding of Jn18:20 to plainly explain Rev.22:12. I don't. But I won't debate that here. My answer stands, and if you disagree with it, that's not a problem for me.

Comment: That was because I was asked to edit it.

Answer (score 1):

The opening statement of the book defines the time of His coming, not the method or how fast He would come, but the amount of time. He said He was coming soon. Christ was telling them that the judgment day was near to them, close to them.  And as history has shown it was only a matter of months from the writing of this prophesy before He returned the 2nd time to those that saw His 1st appearance / manifestation in that generation.  He was coming soon, quickly to fulfill the prophesy of the 2nd destruction of Jerusalem as foretold by the prophets.

> *”The Revelation of Jesus Christ, which God gave unto him, to shew unto his servants things which must shortly come to pass; and he sent and signified it by his angel unto his servant John:”*  (Rev. 1:1, KJV)

ESV, RSV, & NTE: “… what must soon take place…”

CJB: “… what must happen very soon…”

ASV: “… which must shortly come to pass…”

CEV & ERV:  “… what must happen soon…”

GNV:  “… which must shortly be done…”

MSG: “… what is about to happen…”

AMP & NASB:  “...which must soon take place…”

NET: “...must happen very soon…”

NLT: “...that must soon take place…”

YLT: “… behoveth to come to pass quickly...”

Quickly and soon, at hand, and shortly to come to pass all were speaking about a soon to happen event that those of that generation were going to see.  The words were not used to indicate that whenever Jesus decided to return in judgment that His speed indicator would be a fast RPM.  The time was measured in days and months.

The word used for “shortly come to pass” in Rev. 1:1 is Strong’s Gr. 5053, “tachos” and means speed.  Used as quickness, or speed, but also for hastily, and immediately. (Source:  [Biblehub](https://biblehub.com/greek/5034.htm))

Context rules.  The argument for the meaning of the word “soon”, or “shortly” to mean a method of how fast Christ will come in the future is an accommodation, and a rationalization to suit a particular belief.

The word translated as “come to thee quickly” in the YLT at Rev. 2:5 is better translated in the CJB, ESV, NASB, NET, RSV and others as “I will come to you”.  The word in the Interlinear is Strong’s Gr. 2064, “erchomai” and means both to come, or go. (Source: [Biblehub](https://biblehub.com/greek/2064.htm))

The word translated as “quickly” in Rev. 2:16 and 3:11 and 22:12 is Strong’s Gr. 5035, “tachu” which means quickly and speedily.  It is derived from Strong’s Gr. 5036, “taxys” which means promptly.  It is used to mean without delay. (Source: [Biblehub](https://biblehub.com/greek/5035.htm))

The word translated as “which must shortly be done” in Rev. 22:6 (KJV) is Strong’s Gr. 5034, “tachus” and means the same as Strong’s Gr. 5035, quickness, speedily, hastily, immediately. It is the same meaning for hasty action, immediate action as is used in Acts 12:7; 22:18; Rom. 16:20; 1 Tim. 3:14.  All of which meant a time of action or coming, not a method of coming.
Strong’s Concordance: “From the same as tachus; **a brief space (of time)**, i.e. (with en prefixed) in haste -- + quickly, + shortly, + speedily.”  (Source: [Biblehub](https://biblehub.com/greek/5034.htm))

Rev. 22:7, “Behold, I come quickly…” Strong’s Gr 2400 “idou” meaning look, see, behold.  It is an imperative demonstrative participle which adds emphasis to pay attention.  (Source: [Biblehub](https://biblehub.com/greek/2400.htm)) The word “quickly”  is again Strong’s Gr. 5035.

Rev. 22:10, “...for the time is at hand…”  (KJV).   The word in the Interlinear is Strong’s Gr. 1434, “eggu” and means near, in place or time.  Of time, concerning things imminent or soon to come to pass. (Source: [Biblehub](https://biblehub.com/greek/1451.htm))

Context always must rule.  The reason Christ told John not to seal this prophesy was because the time of His coming was near to them, soon to happen.  The words do not mean how He would come, but when He would come.

Today these seven churches and their cities are in ruins.

Sardis was destroyed by the Persians in the 7th century, approx. 616 AD, and today is the site of archaeological digs.  Source: [here](https://www.worldhistory.org/sardis/)

Laodicae was destroyed by a 2nd earthquake in the 5th century AD, and never rebuilt.  The citizens moved to nearby cities such as Denzili.  Today it is an archaeological site. Source: [here](https://www.allaboutturkey.com/laodicea.html)

Philadelphia is now known as Alla-Shehr since it was captured by the Turks and Byzantines in the 14th century AD.   The ancient city and the church are in ruins.  Source: [here](https://bibleatlas.org/philadelphia.htm)

Smyrna fell into the hands of the Turks in 1424 AD, and was rebuilt about 2.5 mi. southeast of the ancient city. The modern city is now called Ismir and surrounds the ruins of the ancient city of Smyrna.  A large part of the ancient city lies buried under modern houses and about 40 mosques. Source: [here](https://bibleatlas.org/smyrna.htm)

Pergamon fell to the Persians approx. 611 AD, and was destroyed.  The Romans took it back about 641 AD and only restored the Acropolis.  Today the ancient ruins are a tourist attraction, the site of archaeological digs. The remains of the ancient city on the lower slopes of the mountain is now called Bergama under Turkish rule since the 14th century AD. Sources: [here](https://www.worldhistory.org/pergamon/) and [here](https://www.britannica.com/place/Pergamum)

Ephesus fell to the Turks in 1408 AD and the people were deported or murdered.  It has been an archaeological site since about 1863 AD.  Source: [here](https://bibleatlas.org/ephesus.htm)

Thyatira is in ruins, and the ancient city is a fenced off area within the Turkish county town of Akhisar.  It most probably fell to the Turks in the 14th century AD.  Sources: [here](https://www.hmdb.org/m.asp?m=119733) and [here](https://www.meandertravel.com/biblical_asia_minor/biblical_asia_minor.php?details=thyatira&m=5&md=sc5) and [here](https://bibleatlas.org/thyatira.htm).

If the prophesy of Revelation has not yet been fulfilled, if it is still waiting for Christ to return at some future unknown date, then the manner of His return as being fast or quick will not matter to any of the seven churches that existed when the letter was written.  How then would this letter apply to currently non-existent churches in non-existent cities today if the prophesy is still future to us?  What future fast-coming judgment matters to those which are not there any more?

Further, the teaching that the book was written about AD 95 during Domitian’s reign has been known to be in error for many years.  Revelation was written before the temple in Jerusalem fell, about AD 66 – AD 68 under the reign of Nero.

> “It was written in Patmos about A.D. 68, whither John had been banished by Domitius Nero, as stated in the title of the Syria version of the book; and with this concurs the express statement of Irenaeus in A.D. 175, who says it happened in the reign of Domitianou – i.e., Domitius (Nero).  Sulpicius, Orosius, etc., stupidly mistaking Domitianou for Domitianikos, supposed Irenaeus to refer to Domitian, A.D. 95, and most succeeding writers have fallen into the same blunder.  The internal testimony is wholly in favor of the early date. The temple at Jerusalem was still standing (ch. 11.1-10); the exact duration of the siege is foretold, viz., 42 months, 3(-)1/2 years, or 1260 days; the two witnesses are to be slain in the city where our Lord was crucified; Nero was reigning at the time, for it is said of the seven kings of Rome; ‘five are fallen, and one is, and the other is not yet come, and when he cometh, he must continue a short space.’ The five kings are Julius Caesar, Augustus, Tiberius, Caligula, Claudius. The ‘one who is ‘ is Nero; the one who ‘must continue for a short space’ is Galba, who reigned only seven months. Everywhere the events are ‘to come quickly,’ lit. ‘with haste,’ or speed (ch. 1.1; 2.16; 3.11; 11.14; 22.7, 12, 20). The escape of the Christian Jews from Jerusalem to Pella is undoubtedly referred to in ch. 7.1-8, compared with Mat. 24.30.’”  (Source: Young’s Analytical Concordance, 1885)

Nero’s birth name was Lucius Domitius Ahenobarbus, and he chose the name Nero Claudius Caesar Drusus Germanicus after he was adopted by Claudius in 50 A.D.  Domitian was born Titus Flavius Domitianius in AD 51, and later became Caesar Domitianus Augustus.  Domitianou and Domitianikos appear to be the Greek form of their names.

There are many commentators and authors of the 18th, 19th and 20th centuries who agreed that Revelation was written before the destruction of Jerusalem and that Herodian temple.

J.A.T. Robinson (1976) from Redating the New Testament, p. 13:

> “One of the oddest facts about the New Testament is that what on any showing would appear to be the single most datable and climactic event of the period — the fall of Jerusalem in A.D. 70 — is never once mentioned as a past fact. . . . [T]he silence is nevertheless as significant as the silence for Sherlock Holmes of the dog that did not bark”.

William Hurte (1884) from Catechetical Commentary: Edinburgh Scotland:

> “That John saw these visions in the reign of Nero, and that they were written by him during his banishment by that emperor, is confirmed by Theophylact, Andreas, Arethas, and others. We judge, therefore, that this book was written about A.D. 68, and this agrees with other facts of history.. There are also several statements in this book which can only be understood on the ground that the judgment upon Jerusalem was then future.”

Arthur Cushman McGiffert (1890) from Eusebius, Church History, Book III, ch.5. Eusebius notes, 148, footnote 1:

> “Internal evidence has driven most modern scholars to the conclusion that the Apocalypse must have been written before the destruction of Jerusalem, the banishment therefore taking place under Nero instead of Domitian.”

James M. MacDonald (1870) from Life and Writings of John, pp 171-172:

> “And when we open the book itself, and find inscribed on its very pages evidence that at the time it was written Jewish enemies were still arrogant and active, and the city in which our Lord was crucified, and the temple and the altar in it were still standing, we need no date from early antiquity, not even from the hand of the author himself, to inform us that he wrote before the great historical event and prophetic epoch, the destruction of Jerusalem.”

B.F. Westcott (1825- 1903) from The Gospel According to St. John pp. clxxiv-clxxv:

> “The Apocalypse is after the close of St. Paul’s work. It shows in its mode of dealing with Old Testament figures a close connexion with the Epistle to the Hebrews (2 Peter, Jude). And on the other hand it is before the destruction of Jerusalem.”

Kenneth L. Gentry, Jr. (1989) from Before Jerusalem Fell, p 336:

> “My confident conviction is that a solid case for a Neronic date for Revelation can be set forth from the available evidences, both internal and external. In fact, I would lean toward a date after the outbreak of the Neronic persecution in late A.D.64 and before the declaration of the Jewish war in early A.D.67. A date in either A.D.65 or early A.D.66 would seem most suitable.”

Greg Bahnsen (1984) from Historical Setting for the Dating of Revelation:

> “When we combine the names (of the pre-20th century advocates of the early dating of the Apocalypse of John) with the yet outstanding stature of Schaff, Terry, Lightfoot, Westcott, and Hort, we can feel the severity of Beckwith’s understatement when, in 1919, he described the Neronian dating for Revelation as “a view held by many down to recent times.”

Revelation must be understood from the contemporary historical view point of those who received that letter in the first century A.D.  As the promises were made to them, as they were told that Christ was coming quickly and soon, the prophesies contained in Revelation cannot be moved in time to a future generation some 2,000 years later. Doing so makes Christ appear to be a liar, and that is blasphemy.  It also deceives those who might otherwise believe the word of God.  They frequently make the argument that Jesus said He was coming soon, but according to the current teaching He hasn’t yet come almost 2,000 years later, so why should they believe Him?

We also need to learn some of the Jewish idioms. There is background to the phrase "no one knows the day or the hour."

The first day of the month had to wait for the official declaration from the Sanhedrin.  Because the first day of the month had to be validated by the two witnesses, it affected the time for attending the holy convocation for the Day of Trumpets / Yom Teruah on the 1st of Tishri.  The Hebrews could not know exactly on which day it would be held as they were waiting for the appearance of the new moon.

A tradition grew and a saying in Israel became popular as “no one knows the day or the hour.”

> *"But of that day and hour knoweth no man, no, not the angels of heaven, but my Father only.”*  (Matt. 24:36, KJV)

**In the chapter discussing the destruction of the temple, Christ deliberately used the Hebraic idiom for the Day of Trumpets.**  He told his disciples the day the temple would be completely destroyed – Yom Teruah!

And indeed that temple was completely torn down by the Romans by the time of the 1st of Tishri, AD 70.  See my post The Signs of The Feasts - Part II: Christ Told His Disciples When He Would Return [here](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2018/07/21/the-signs-of-the-feasts-part-ii-christ-told-his-disciples-when-he-would-return/)

The words quickly and soon are speaking of the amount of TIME, not the manner or method of His 2nd coming to them.

Comment: Having read this, I do not see what answer you have provided.  Are you suggesting that the destruction of Jerusalem in AD 70 was the coming of Jesus?  If so, is Jesus not returning visibly as per Matt 24 to raise the dead, etc.  If not, then what are you suggesting?

Comment: @Dottard - the ? was how to understand the word quickly in our concept of time.  It is revering to how soon Christ would return.  His return was "coming in the clouds" of Matt. 24:30; 26:64, Mark 13:26; 14:62 which is prophetic judgment language which is not literal.  It is figurative.  Can Christ only come in judgment twice?  How much limit are you going to bind him with.  His 2nd coming was for judgment (Heb. 9:28) & could only happen in the same generation as those who saw His first coming in that generation.  The judgment against Jerusalem as the "end of the days" of Daniel's 490 years...

Comment: Matt. 25 is still part of the prophesy of the destruction of the temple in Matt. 24, when Christ told them He would come in judgment & release those in the grave (Hades) & when Daniel was told He would stand in his lot / order.  The end of the days of Daniel 12 were the end of the days for the desolations of Daniel's holy city (Dan. 9:24) which happened at the destruction of Jerusalem in AD 70.  Jesus judges the nations still, and & can come in judgment any time He needs to.  More at Testing the Spirits Part II - The End, & Part III - Daniel's Lot - ...

Comment: here - https://shreddingtheveil.org/2022/01/24/testing-the-spirits-part-ii-the-end/  & here - https://shreddingtheveil.org/2022/02/12/testing-the-spirits-part-iii-daniels-lot/.  You have to see with the proper perspective, & get rid of that taught idea that is clouding what you read.  An end of the world, end of time scenario of the futurist perspective is never taught in God's word.  IT is the product of man's teaching, and Jewish fables.

Comment: OK.  Thanks.  Then why did you not put that in your answer rather that hinting at it?

Comment: I thought I had, both at the beginning and in the middle and in the end.

Comment: My apologies - I must be stupid - I still cannot see it.

Comment: Is that any better?

Comment: Thanks, Gina.  I stridently disagree with your praxis, but thank you for the (now) clear explanation of your preterist views.  This is helpful.

Comment: Preterist views... Believing what the Bible says in not a 'view"... it is abiding by the very clear statements Jesus made.

Comment: I understand your position.  However, your "position" required that you accommodate the Biblical language by making some literal statements into metaphorical ones and vis versa.  But this is not the place for debate and do not want to debate - I come here to learn from others, especially those with whom I disagree.

Answer (score 0):

The word "quickly", refers to a situation that nobody knows when the Lord come. When the Lord arrived, time is up, and He will render to each man according as his work is. It urges each man when he knows his sin, repent in this moment, don't wait for the next second, for the Lord may come the next second, and his time is up.

The word "quickly" does not refer to the exact timeline of the Lord. It is a relative timeline of us, for each of us only has one life, one opportunity to receive our redemption. It urges us to act quickly to response the calling of the Lord, for nobody knows when the Lord come. When He arrived, the final judgement concluded.

> Matthew 24:36 - “But about that day or hour no one knows, not even the angels in heaven, nor the Son, but only the Father. (NIV)
>
> Matthew 24:42 - “Therefore keep watch, because you do not know on what day your Lord will come. (NIV)
>
> Matthew 25:13 - “Therefore keep watch, because you do not know the day or the hour. (NIV)

To emphasize the essence of "quick" response, Matthew arranged two parables of Jesus to remind the disciples to "keep watch", if they didn't want to be throw into the darkness, where there will be weeping and gnashing of teeth. These two parables are;

- The Parable of wise and wicked servant, in Matthew 24:45-51
- The Parable of the Ten Virgins, in Matthew 25:1-13